# After making a reservation, the reserved time does not disappear from the list of available times

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a project where you can arrange training with a trainer. And I have a problem with booking a training session, because after making a reservation, the time that was booked does not disappear from the available time. On the same day, another person can also book this hour.

```
Models.py



class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class WorkingHour(models.Model):
    time = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def reserve_hour(self):
        if self.is_available:
            self.is_available = False
            self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.time


class Trainer(BaseModel):
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=type_job)
    working_hours = models.ManyToManyField(WorkingHour, related_name='trainers', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.trainer.first_name} {self.trainer.last_name} - {self.job}"


class TrainerServices(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Appointment(BaseModel):
    date = models.DateField()
    chosen_hour = models.ForeignKey(WorkingHour, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class TrainerAppointment(Appointment):
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    services = models.ForeignKey(TrainerServices, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}-{self.services}"
```

```
Forms.py


class TrainerAppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    chosen_hour = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=WorkingHour.objects.filter(is_available=True),
        empty_label=None,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-select is_valid"})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = TrainerAppointment
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "trainer": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-select is_valid"}),
            "date": forms.DateInput(attrs={"class": "form-control is_valid", "type": "date"}),
            "services": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-select is_valid"}),
        }

    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data.get('date')
        today = timezone.now().date()
        if date < today:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Niepoprawna data. Wybierz właściwą datę.")
        return date
```

```
Views.py


class TrainerAppointmentCreate(CreateView):
    model = TrainerAppointment
    form_class = TrainerAppointmentForm
    template_name = 'create_appointment.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.entries > 0:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.save()

            self.request.user.entries -= 1
            self.request.user.save()

            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            form.add_error(None, "Nie masz pakietu treningów. Zakup proszę pakiet.")
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

This is my code. Full code is here :

https://github.com/Nowacki97PL/GrowUP

Answer (score 1):

Just from a glance I am not seeing where you're setting `is_available` to `False` once a booking is confirmed.